# TypeError: top20 is not iterable

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, discord

**Hi!**

I have problems with my code:

```
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}btop`)) {
  const top20 = db
    .prepare('SELECT * FROM bufferpoints WHERE userid = ? ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 20;')
    .all();
  const btopembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(message.guild.name + "'s" + 'TOP Buffercheckers!')
    .setColor('#900C3F')
    .setFooter('oPOp')
    .setTimestamp();
  var sum = 0;

  for (const data of top20) {
    sum++;

    var numb = data.points.toString();
    var addComma = numb.replace(/(.)(?=(.{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
    btopembed.addField(sum + ' .', bot.users.get(data.user) + ` ~ ${addComma}`);
  }
  message.channel.send(btopembed);
}
```

After i run the command i get error:  `TypeError: top20 is not iterable`

I have no idea how to fix it :(

**Thanks for your help!**

Comment: You need to see what is the type of top20, because to iterate it with for of, it needs to be an Array or a Map.

Comment: @Oscar Velandia and how do i do that ?

Comment: you can do console.log(typeof top20, top20)  with this console.log you will see the type of  top20 and the value it have

Comment: still getting the same error ;/

Comment: what is the response you get from console.log?

Comment: Do you have to "bind" a value to the `?` placeholder?

Comment: @Oscar Velandia i get something like this: 
Statement { sql: 'SELECT * FROM donos ORDER BY money DESC LIMIT 20;' }

Comment: i changed the databse a bit